# Arithmetic progressions inside polynomial sets

Tags: additive-combinatorics, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-progression

There are at most 3 perfect squares in arithmetic progression (Fermat, Euler). It was shown in [1] that if $n>2$ there are no three term arithmetic progression consisting of nth powers.

Take a *non-linear* polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients and consider the polynomial set $ A_p = p(\mathbb{N})  $. Let $f(A)$ be the maximal length over all arithmetic progressions whose elements are in $A$. It is not hard to prove, reducing it to the perfect squares case, that if the $\deg(p)=2$ then $f(A_p)<4$.

**Question 1**: Is it true that $f(A_p)$ is always finite if $\deg(p) >1$ ?

It is clear that there are no infinite arithmetic progressions inside polynomial sets, but I do not see how to exclude the possibility of having arbitrarily large AP.

**Question 2**: Is there a uniform bound for $f(A_p)$ over all polynomials $p(x)$ with $\deg(p)=k$ ?

For example, can we find $10$ terms in arithmetic progression whose elements belong to some polynomial set $A_p$ with $\deg(p)=3$?

[1]  H. Darmon and L. Merel, Winding quotients and some variants of Fermat’s
Last Theorem, J. Reine Angew. Math. 490 (1997), 81–100.

Comment: If there was no uniform bound for $f(A_p)$ for degree three polynomials, then (after scaling etc) I could find a cubic $f(x)$ and rationals $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$...$x_{1000000}$ such that $f(x_n)=n$. Now because 1000 of these $n$ are squares I have now got 1000 points on $y^2=f(x)$ and now *perhaps* I am pretty close to constructing elliptic curves with arbitrarily large rank. It's unclear to me what the concensus is about these things existing. Similarly I can construct curves of genus 3, say, over Q with as many points as you like and again it's not clear that such things should exist.

Comment: Don't terms in arithmetic progression lie on a straight line, and we are talking about the intersection of a polynomial with a straight line?

Comment: This doesn't help with your problem, but it is interesting to note that as soon as we allow two variables, we get arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions from only a quadratic example: the polynomial $x^2+y^2$, for example. This is an immediate consequence of the Green-Tao theorem.

Comment: @Mark: The points do not have to be on a straight line. Take for example (1,1), (5,25) and (7, 49) which correspond to the 3-AP of squares 1, 25, 49.

Answer (score 4):

[Edited to give direct connection with Caporaso-Harris-Mazur via Kevin Buzzard's idea]

Such results are probably true but out of reach of present-day techniques.  For each $p$ or $k$, and every sufficiently large $n$ (say $n>k$), the $n$-term arithmetic progressions of the desired type are parametrized by nontrivial points on some algebraic variety, call it $V_n$, of fixed dimension: dimension $2$ if $p$ is fixed (assuming it's not of the form $a(x-x_0)^k+b$ in which case we're back to Darmon-Merel), and degree about $k$ if $p$ is allowed to vary over all polynomials of degree $k$.  In each case we have for each $n$ two maps $V_n \rightarrow V_{n-1}$ of degree $k$ that forget the first or last term of the progression; and $V_n$ should be of general type for $n$ large enough.  We're now in a setting similar to that of [this recent Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73346) (#73346), and I give much the same answer as [I did for that question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73346/#73377): the claim should follow from the Bombieri-Lang conjectures plus some possibly nontrivial extra work, as in

> L.Caporaso, J.Harris, and B.Mazur: Uniformity of rational points, *J. Amer. Math. Soc.* **10** #1 (1997), 1-45

but (excluding some very special cases that don't seem relevant here) we have no techniques for proving such results unconditionally on varieties of dimension greater than 1.

**EDIT** Indeed this is a special case of Caporaso-Harris-Mazur, by adapting Kevin Buzzard's observation in his comment on the original question: write the equations as $f(x_m)=m$ $(m=1,2,\ldots,n)$ for some degree-$k$ polynomial $f$ (obtained from $p$ by suitable translation and scaling), and consider just those $m$ in that range which are of the form (say) $y^5$ or $y^5+1$.  By Mason's theorem (polynomial ABC) either $f$ or $f-1$ has at least two zeros whose order is not a multiple of $5$, so either $f(x) = y^5$ or $f(x)=y^5+1$ defines a curve of genus at least $2$.  But the genus is clearly $O(k)$ for any polynomial $f$ of degree $k$.  So, if the number of rational points on such a curve has a uniform bound, then so does the length of an arithmetic progression of values of a polynomial of bounded degree.

Come to think of it, the reduction to C-H-M could also be obtained more directly from the curve $p(x')-p(x)=d$ (for $k>3$), or $p(x''')-p(x'')=p(x'')-p(x')=p(x')-p(x)=d$ (to cover $k=2$ and $k=3$ as well), where $d$ is some multiple of the common difference of the arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Lagrange interpolation tell you that you can fit $n+1$ numbers (even if $n$ are in an arithmetic progression) to a non-linear polynomial of degree $n$? and if the common difference is divisible by the right numbers, said polynomial will have integer coefficients?

Comment: An edit made this a bit unclear: The original form of the question makes clear that question 2 is meant as unform for for a fixed k.

Comment: @Gerry: The polynomial degree is fixed. I have changed the original formulation to make it more clear. 

Comment: Oops.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Polynomial of degree at most $n$ - you will get a straight line surely?

Comment: @Mark, note it's $n$ numbers in AP, together with one more number not in the AP, so the polynomial of degree (at most) $n$ won't be a straight line. 

Answer (score 0):

For a very particular case, when de degree of the polynomial is 3 and the arithmatic progression has reason not congruent to 3, then the polynomial can't have an arithmetic progression with more than 4 elements.
I can send you the proof if you want it.

Comment: Post please!   .

Answer (score -2):

I think I have a proof, given by a friend of mine. I’m going to post the proof when the degree is 3, but it is easy to do a generalization.

Assume $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx$, and for all $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ we have $p(a_i)=ir$. Consider the equation
$$p(x)-ir=0 \iff bx^2 + cx + (ax^3-ir)=0 \iff x=\frac1{2b}\left(-c \pm \sqrt{c^2-4b(ax^3-ir)}\right),$$
if we calculate the derivative in order to $x$ we have:
$$1=\frac1{4b}\frac{-12b\cdot ax^2}{\sqrt{c^2-4b(ax^3-ir)}} \iff \sqrt{c^2-4b(ax^3-ir)}=-3ax^2,$$ 
so in the equation $x=\frac1{2b}\left(-c \pm\sqrt{c^2-4b(ax^3-ir)}\right)$ we have $x=\frac1{2b}(-3ax^2)$.

Every one of the $a_i$’s not equal to zero must satisfy the last equation, since it is a degree $2$ polynomial we only have, at maximum, $2$ solutions, hence a arithmetic progression must have maximal length equal to $3$.

The general case follows more or less in this way, we use the $2$-degree formula, and take the derivative in order to $x$, which will give us a polynomial equation of $n-1$ degree.

Sorry, but I can't write LATEX...
Please tell me if it is correct.

Comment: The reasoning is not correct: the equation $p(x)-ir=0$ only holds for the isolated points $a_i$, not in their neighbourhoods, hence taking derivatives will not preserve the equality. Note that your argument never used the assumption that $a_i$’s are integers, but then the result does not hold, there are infinite arithmetic progressions with real $a_i$ (since the range of $p$ is all of $\mathbb R$ or a one-side unbounded interval).