# Special arithmetic progressions involving perfect squares

Tags: diophantine-equations, discrete-mathematics, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-progression

Prove that there are infinitely many positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$ that are consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression and also satisfy the condition that $ab+1$, $bc+1$, $ca+1$ are all perfect squares.

I believe this can be done using Pell's equation. What is interesting however is that the following result for four numbers apparently holds:

Claim. There are no positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ that are consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression and also satisfy the condition that $ab+1$, $ac+1$, $ad+1$, $bc+1$, $bd+1$, $cd+1$ are all perfect squares.

I am curious to see if there is any (decent) solution.

Thanks.

Comment: //Apologies if the tags are not appropriate; didn't know where elementary nt fits better (if it fits at all on this website)

Comment: What do you mean by "apparently holds"? Have you checked it computationally, or can you derive it from the three-term progression case?

Comment: I checked it computationally, sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: I added the "diophantine-equations" tag.

See also my comment on duje's answer below relating to the case of triples in AP.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607501/multiples-that-are-one-less-than-squares

Comment: For your first paragraph, let $a,b,c = -x + 2y,\,2y,\,x+2y$. Then, $$ab+1=(-x + 2y)(2y) + 1 = (x - y)^2\\ac+1=(-x + 2y)(x + 2y) + 1 = y^2\\bc+1=(2y)(x + 2y) + 1 = (x + y)^2$$ where $x^2-3y^2=1$ which proves the three-term case has infinitely many integer solutions. See this [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120391/clever-use-of-pells-equation).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting from the equations in my previous answer, we get, by multiplying them in pairs,
$$(x-y)x(x+y)(x+2y) + (x-y)x + (x+y)(x+2y) + 1 = (z_1 z_6)^2\,,$$
$$(x-y)x(x+y)(x+2y) + (x-y)(x+y) + x(x+2y) + 1 = (z_2 z_5)^2\,,$$
$$(x-y)x(x+y)(x+2y) + (x-y)(x+2y) + x(x+y) + 1 = (z_3 z_4)^2\,.$$
Write $u = z_1 z_6$, $v = z_2 z_5$, $w = z_3 z_4$ and take differences to obtain
$$3 y^2 = u^2 - v^2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad y^2 = v^2 - w^2\,.$$
The variety $C$ in ${\mathbb P}^3$ described by these two equations is a smooth curve of genus 1 whose Jacobian elliptic curve is 24a1 in the Cremona database; this elliptic curve has rank zero and a torsion group of order 8. This implies that $C$ has exactly 8 rational points; up to signs they are given by $(u:v:w:y) = (1:1:1:0)$ and $(2:1:0:1)$. So $y = 0$ or $w = 0$. In the first case, we do not have an honest AP ($y$ is the difference). In the second case, we get the contradiction $abcd + ad + bc + 1 = 0$ ($a,b,c,d$ are supposed to be positive). So unless I have made a mistake somewhere, this proves that there are no such APs of length 4.

**Addition:** We can apply this to *rational* points on the surface. The case $y = 0$ gives a bunch of conics of the form 
$$x^2 + 1 = z_1^2, \quad z_2 = \pm z_1, \quad \dots, \quad z_6 = \pm z_1\,;$$
the case $w = 0$ leads to $ad = -1$ or $bc = -1$. The second of these gives $ad + 1 < 0$, and the first gives $ac + 1 = (a^2 + 1)/3$, which cannot be a square. This shows that all the rational points are on the conics mentioned above; in particular, *(weak) Bombieri-Lang holds for this surface*.

Comment: @Michael: Very nice! Let $X$ denote the surface given by your earlier answer. Then if I understand correctly, you've given a dominant rational map $X\to C$, where $C$ has genus 1 and $#C(\mathbb{Q})=8$. It seems a little surprising that a surface of general type should map onto a genus 1 curve, although I guess the fact that $X$ is an intersection of quadrics gives it a chance. But did you have some *a priori* reason to suspect that $X$ admitted such a covering?

Comment: @Joe: I didn't have some good *a priori* reason to suspect that $X$ would map to a genus 1 curve, but the observation that the analogous problem for five terms admits such a map (to the "four squares in AP" curve) provided some motivation to try a little bit longer.

Comment: Bravo!  The identities look a bit less mysterious if the arithmetic progression is written symmetrically as $(x-3y,x-y,x+y,x+3y)$, when the products $(z_i z_{7-i})^2$ are invariant under $y \leftrightarrow -y$  (Then $u^2-v^2$ and $v^2-w^2$ are $12y^2$ and $4y^2$, which comes to the same curves over ${\bf Q}$.)

Comment: Can magma (or other software) detect the nontrivial $H^1$ of this surface which makes this analysis possible?

Comment: Hm. I guess you would want the `$H^1$` of its desingularization, which might be a fairly complicated object. As damiano pointed out to me by email, the fact that there is a map to an elliptic curve must be related to the singularities being sufficiently bad (otherwise the surface would be simply connected).

Answer (score 7):

Already for three-term progressions it's somewhat surprising that
there are infinitely many solutions, because the usual probabilistic
guess for the expected number of solutions leads to a convergent sum:
a random number of size $M$ is a square with probability about
$M^{-1/2}$, so we're summing something like $1/(abc)$ over all three-term progressions
$(a,b,c)$, etc.  To be sure such a guess cannot account for non-random
patterns arising from polynomial identities, but it does suggest that
past a certain point such identities will be the only source of solutions.

Now a mindless exhaustive search over progressions
$(x,x+y,x+2y)$ with $0 < x,y < 10^4$ finds only the first six examples
$$
(1,7),\phantom+
(4,26),\phantom+
(15,97),\phantom+
(56,362),\phantom+
(209,1351),\phantom+
(780,5042)
$$
of an infinite family associated with the solutions
$(2,1)$, $(7,4)$, $(26,15)$, $(97,56)$, $(362,209)$, $(1351,780)$, etc.
of the Pell equation $x^2-3y^2=1$.  If it can be proved that these are
the only solutions then it will immediately follow that there are
no four-term arithmetic progressions with the same property.
But that seems like a very hard problem.

Here's the **gp** code; with a bound of $10^4$ it takes only
a few minutes.  One can surely do better with a more intelligent
search procedure (e.g. start by finding all solutions of $ab+1=r^2$
by factoring $r^2-1$).

```
H = 10^4
progsq(x,y,n) = sum(i=0,n-2,sum(j=i+1,n-1,issquare((x+i*y)*(x+j*y)+1)))
for(x=1,H,for(y=1,H,if(progsq(x,y,3)==3,print([x,y]))))
```

Comment: Isn't there a similar problem involving 1,3,8,120, that says something like there is no fifth member such that the product of any two is one less than a square?  It might be also that there are finitely many quadruplets, with the nontrivial ones being not arithmetic progressions.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Obscure Puzzles" Paseman, 2012.02.11

Comment: I was reminded of this 1,3,8,120 puzzle too, because Martin Gardner wrote about it in one of his columns decades ago and reported that the nonexistence of a fifth positive integer was proved only with difficulty (including several 1000+ digit computations, back when that was impressive).  But there are infinitely many such integer quadruplets.  A few Google searches turned up http://vixra.org/pdf/0907.0024v1.pdf with citations going as far as Euler and Diophantus!  But naturally none of these are four-term arithmetic progressions...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is essentially what I did to claim that I "checked it manually": I verified the correspondence between the solutions of the problem in question and $x^{2}-3y^{2}=1$ up to $10^{9}$ and then just assummed this to be true.

I was hoping however to find some slick way of doing the four number case without refering to the three case :).

Comment: You're welcome.  You saw that by now M.Stoll has completely solved the 4-term problem, even over the rationals.  For the 3-term problem, you write that you "checked manually" up to $10^9$; how did you do that?  I used the factorization of $t^2-1$ in $bc+1=t^2$ to search up to $t = 10^8$ in a few hours, still finding only the Pell solutions up to $(a,b,c) = (7865521, 58709048, 109552575)$; so $t=10^9$ (if that's what you meant) is feasible too, though it would take a while (or a number of CPU's running in parallel) to finish − and it's certainly not "manual" in the usual sense of "by hand"...

Answer (score 7):

According to Magma, the projective closure of the variety associated to the problem (given by the equations
$$x(x-y) + 1 = z_1^2, \quad (x+y)(x-y) + 1 = z_2^2, \quad (x+2y)(x-y) + 1 = z_3^2,$$
$$(x+y)x + 1 = z_4^2, \quad (x+2y)x + 1 = z_5^2, \quad (x+2y)(x+y) + 1 = z_6^2 \quad)$$
is an irreducible surface in ${\mathbb P}^8$ with 34 isolated singularities. Since it is a complete intersection of six quadrics, it should be of general type (and it has trivial rational points with $x = y = 0$ and slightly less trivial ones with $y = 0$, so reduction methods will not work), which makes it very likely that this is a hard question.

**Added later:** You may want to look at [Question 73346](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73346) for an explanation by Noam Elkies of the reasoning behind this.

Comment: This suggests that indeed the *rational* points are likewise fully accounted for by finitely many curves.  The question asked only for integer points, which could conceivably be more tractable, though I don't see how.

Comment: @Noam: The problem with three terms should give a K3 Surface. Are there any K3-related methods that might prove that (up to signs) all the integral points are on the curve that comes from the Pell equation?

Comment: There are no solutions with five terms $a,b,c,d,e$ in arithmetic progression, since then $ab+1$, $ac+1$, $ad+1$, $ae+1$ would have to be four squares in arithmetic progression. Of course, this doesn't really help...

Comment: @Michael: It might be an interesting K3 surface but I don't see how to use this to prove anything about its integral points (for which it's of "log-general type").

Answer (score 4):

Dujella has written many papers on Diophantine m-tuples, check out his webpage.

Answer (score 4):

Michael Stoll has given a nice answer, but here is a 17th century argument.
  Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be an arithmetic progression
  with common difference $\Delta \ne 0$.
  Suppose that
  $$1 + a b = z^2_1, \quad 1 + a c = z^2_2, \qquad 1 + a d = z^2_3,$$
  $$1 + b c = z^2_4, \quad 1 + b d = z^2_5, \qquad 1 + c d = z^2_6.$$
 Consider the following quantities:
   $$A =  2 z^2_2 z^2_5  - z^2_1 z^2_6,$$
   $$B =  z_2 z_3 z_4 z_5 - \Delta \cdot z_1 z_6,$$
  $$C  =  z_1 z_3 z_4 z_6 - 2 \Delta \cdot z_2 z_5,$$
  $$D =  z_1 z_2 z_5 z_6 - 3 \Delta \cdot z_3 z_4.$$
  Then one may easily compute that
  $$A^2, B^2, C^2, D^2$$
  is an arithmetic progression. In particular, if the $z_i$ are rational, then we have
  constructed an arithmetic progression of four squares, contradicting a theorem of Fermat.

To be careful, we also have to check that this arithmetic progression of squares has non-trivial difference. A little algebra shows this can only happen (assuming $\Delta \ne 0$) if one of the following equations holds:
   $$ (1 + a d)(1 + b c) = 0,  \quad (1 + a d)(1 + b c) = 2 \Delta^2.$$
The first of these equations leads to no rational solutions (as in Michael's answer), the second says that a square ($z^2_3 z^2_4$) is equal to twice a (non-zero) square, which is also impossible.

Comment: To relate this to Michael's answer, Fermat's four square problem is well known to equivalent to computing $X_0(24)(\mathbf{Q})$. To see the equivalence, if $1$, $1+t$, $1+2t$, and $1+3t$ are squares, then one has a rational point on $s^2 = (1+t)(1+2t)(1+3t)$ which is $X_0(24)$. The converse is slightly more subtle; one has to take points in the corresponding coset of the $2$-Selmer group.

Answer (score 2):

In Diophantine quadruple $a<b<c<d$, it holds $d\ge 4bc$ (see e.g. Lemma 14 in http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/bound.pdf ).

Comment: To complete this: From `$d \ge 4bc$`, it follows easily that $a,b,c,d$ cannot be an AP.

Note also the following: Acdording to Lemma 13 in Dujella's paper linked to in his answer above, if $a,b,c$ is a Diophantine triple with $a < b < c$, then `$c = a + b + 2 \sqrt{ab+1}$` or `$c \ge 4ab$`.
If $a,b,c$ form an AP, then the second possibility cannot occur, and the first (together with the AP condition) then implies that $b$ is even and `$y^2 - 3(b/2)^2 = 1$`, where $y = b-a = c-b$. So it is indeed the case that all such triples come from this Pell equation. (This gives another proof.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to solve a more formal task.  We write the system.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&ab+T=x^2\\&ac+T=y^2\\&bc+T=z^2\end{aligned}\right.$$

We need to find solutions $a,b,c$ - that was an arithmetic progression.  This will help the solution of the equation Pell.

$$p^2-3s^2=T$$

Knowing any solution of the equation Pell $(p_0;s_0)$ you can always find the following formula.

$$p_1=2p_0+3s_0$$

$$s_1=p_0+2s_0$$

Having any decision - can immediately write down the solution of this system.

$$a=2s-p$$

$$b=2s$$

$$c=2s+p$$

$$x=s-p$$

$$y=s$$

$$z=s+p$$

Interesting here is that the $x,y,z$ looks like an arithmetic progression.