# Consecutive square values of cubic polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

Let $P(x)$ be a cubic polynomial with integer coefficients. Does there exist a constant $c$ such that at least one of the following values $P(0),P(1),...,P(c)$ is not a square?

It is known that the number of integral points of $y^2 = P(x)$ is bounded by a constant dependent on the coefficients of $P(x)$ and I am wondering whether in this particular case, it is possible to find a constant independent of the coefficients. Any links to existing literature or maybe an explanation of why such a problem would be impossible to solve with current tools would be of a great help too.

Comment: Just to bound $c$ from below: the polynomial $24x^3-135x^2+192x$ has square values at $0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Let me just point out that you can't hope to find a bound for $c$ by local methods. Indeed, for any $N>0$, we can choose integers $a_1,a_2,a_3$ that are $p$-adically small enough, so that $a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+1$ will be a square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $0\leq x\leq N$.

Comment: Another one square from 0 to 4 is $2x^3 - 10x^2 + 12x$

Comment: Related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50661/unboundedness-of-number-of-integral-points-on-elliptic-curves

Comment: By results of Masser and Zannier on unlikely intersections, to the effect that the points with $x$-coordinates $0,1,\ldots,N$ tend to be independent on a varying elliptic curve, a negative answer to your question would yield elliptic curves of arbitrarily high rank over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Dear Vesselin: is this a heuristic prediction or can you actually prove your statement?

Comment: @René: Actually, see Theorem C in Silverman's 1983 paper "Heights and the specialization map for families of abelian varieties." (An elementary special case which suffices here is proven in Masser's Appendix C to Zannier's book "Some problems of unlikely intersections in arithmetic and geometry.") Already it implies that for a given $N$, there are just finitely many elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ on which, for some Weierstrass equation $y^2 = P(x)$, the points with $x$-coordinates $0,1,\ldots,N$ (and one choice for the square roots in the $y$-coordinates) are dependent.

Comment: @René: Actually, I was hasty, and I have to apologize. Silverman's theorem only applies to one-parameter families. What I said in the previous comment is true for the universal family over $\mathbb{A}_j^1$ and, with some care (e.g., note that $(0,0)$ will be a point of order $2$ as soon as $P(0) = 0$), along any one-parameter family of polynomials $P_{\lambda} \in \mathbb{Q}[x][\lambda]$. To settle my claim one needs more arguments. Still, I believe it should be possible to show along the lines of Silverman-Masser that [continued]

Comment: [continued] the rank of the group spanned by the points with $x$-coordinates $0,1,\ldots,N$ on $E: \, y^2 = P(x)$ approaches infinity as $N, h(j(E)) \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you, Vesselin. I certainly feel inclined to believe the statement that you think is provable. If I would have to prove it I would feel tempted to use the $2$-descent map, but I am not sure if that'd work.

Comment: Büchi's (open) problem might be relevant in that context. Namely, I quote H. Pasten Vasquez's thesis : « Does there exist an integer $M$ such that the only monic polynomials of degree two $F \in \Bbb Z[X]$ satisfying that $F(1), . . . , F (M )$ are integer squares, are precisely of the form $F(X)=(X+c)^2$ for some $c \in \Bbb Z$? »

Answer (score 10):

I show here that the existence of such a constant $c$ (and much more) follows from previous conjectures.

Namely, a special case of the Caporaso-Harris-Mazur conjecture asserts that there is a constant $N$ such that: for any squarefree degree-$6$ polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbf{Q}[x]$, there are at most $N$ rational numbers $b$ for which $f(b)$ is a square (in $\mathbf{Q}$).  So if $P(x)$ is a cubic polynomial in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ for which $P(x)P(x+1)$ is squarefree, then there are at most $N$ rational numbers $b$ for which both $P(b)$ and $P(b+1)$ are squares, whence you can take $N+1$ to be your constant $c$.  If $P(x)$ is squarefree but $P(x)P(x+1)$ is not, then one can use the above argument with $P(x)P(x+r)$ for some $r\in\{2,3,4\}$, as at least one of these will be squarefree.  If $P(x)$ is not squarefree then we can divide it by a square factor in order to reduce to the analogous question for degree-one polynomials, where it's easy to exhibit such a value $c$.

Answer (score 9):

[**EDITED** *to fix typos, show smoothness of $V_c$,
and extend the exhaustive-search result*]

Solutions of $P(i) = y_i^2$ ($0 \leq i \leq c$)
with $P(X) = \sum_{j=0}^3 a_j X^j$ are parametrized up to scaling by
a threefold $V_c$ in projective space ${\bf P}^c$ that's
the complete intersection of $c-3$ quadrics
$$
y_i^2 - 4 y_{i+1}^2 + 6 y_{i+2}^2 - 4 y_{i+3}^2 + y_{i+4}^2 = 0
\phantom{0\infty}
(0 \leq i \leq c-4),
$$
minus the points on the hyperplane $y_0^2 - 3 y_1^2 + 3 y_2^2 - y_3^2 = 0$
where the leading coefficient $a_3$ vanishes.  We expect plenty of points
for $c < 7$, a sparse but still infinite set of points for $c = 7$,
and only finitely many points for $c > 7$ except possibly on a
proper subvariety.   This last part is a special case of the Bombieri-Lang
conjecture, and if we assume this conjecture for $V_8$ then we can probably
use the forgetful maps $V_c \rightarrow V_8$ for $c>8$ to prove
(more directly than using Caporaso-Harris-Mazur as **Michael Zieve** proposed)
that some $V_c$ has no rational points except on the hyperplane $a_3=0$.

[**EDIT** René's comment raises the question of whether this
complete intersection is smooth.  The answer is yes in characteristic zero.
Any linear combination of the differentials of the quadrics
$y_i^2 - 4 y_{i+1}^2 + 6 y_{i+2}^2 - 4 y_{i+3}^2 + y_{i-4}^2$
has the form $(a_0 y_0, a_1 y_1, \ldots, a_c y_c)$ with
$\sum_{m=0}^c Q(m) a_m = 0$ for any polynomial $Q(m)$ of degree at most $3$.
Therefore in any nonzero combination at least $5$ of the $a_m$ do not vanish.
Therefore at a singularity at least $5$ of the $y_i$ must be zero.
But this is impossible because $y_i^2$ are valuees of a cubic polynomial
at distinct points $i=0,1,\ldots,c$, and at most $3$ of those can be zero
unless the polynomial vanishes identically.]

An exhaustive search for rational points on $V_7$ with $a_3 \neq 0$ and
$0 \leq y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5 < 1024$ finds only the following $22$
[**EDIT** extended from $1024 = 2^{10}$ to $1536 = 3 \cdot 2^9$,
and found eight more solutions, for a total of $30$],
up to the symmetry $y_i \leftrightarrow y_{7-i}$:

```
13 7 1 1 5 7 7 1
53 21 7 29 45 53 49 3
1586 847 24 73 610 861 868 221
139 23 31 115 173 209 217 181
1061 577 35 73 469 721 883 935
31 52 47 34 35 64 107 158
821 433 49 127 355 479 473 79
139 83 71 97 125 139 127 41
359 19 79 299 439 509 481 229
163 124 107 110 121 128 121 82
169 157 119 67 55 131 233 349
368 247 134 35 76 163 242 311
826 481 164 1 286 451 544 539
323 223 167 167 197 223 223 167
595 379 187 17 109 205 251 217
973 109 239 817 1195 1387 1319 679
497 323 247 283 353 397 377 203
676 499 266 121 416 799 1226 1691
34 369 332 185 138 419 784 1203
2258 1259 356 235 838 1183 1216 521
1393 927 449 229 705 1273 1873 2499
2836 1597 470 223 1016 1471 1562 925
1373 889 475 211 317 497 581 475
1179 728 581 750 977 1124 1113 794
2027 1315 673 199 499 917 1255 1487
1027 1064 749 50 343 1252 2239 3334
2573 1629 791 65 507 923 1121 969
961 896 817 802 925 1196 1579 2042
1297 1082 827 608 613 922 1393 1948
1144 1135 854 413 388 1099 1970 2951
```

none of these lifts to a rational point on $V_8$
(neither $P(-1)$ nor $P(8)$ is a square); possibly
$c=8$ is already small enough th make a solution impossible.

Comment: Very nice answer. By the way, the minus in one of the indices in your displayed formula should be a plus. (I deleted my previous comment, whose validity rested on the assumption that the $V_c$ are smooth. I thought I had an easy proof of this, but it was wrong.)

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed the typo you noted (and also un-overloaded the index $i$),
and gave a proof of the smoothness of $V_c$ (and took the opportunity
to extend the exhaustive search a bit).

Answer (score 5):

Lower bound for $c$ is <strike>6</strike> $7$.

$$ f(x) = -5096*x^3 + 70161*x^2 - 232960*x + 262144 $$ is square for $ x \in [0,6]$.

This is specialization of the identity which is square for $x \in [0,5]$:

$$ P_5 = \left(2 b_{0} + \frac{75}{8}\right) x^{3} + \left(-15 b_{0} - \frac{4311}{64}\right) x^{2} + \left(\frac{115}{4} b_{0} + 120\right) x + b_{0}^{2}$$

For $0 \le x \le 7$

$g(x)=4*x^3 - 36*x^2 + 80*x + 1$

If I remember correctly, the related question for quadratic is conjecturally bounded by about $8$.

**Added**

The $P_5$ identity gave infinite family of $8$ solutions arising
from genus $1$ curve (to avoid scaling require the content to be square free).

I believe absolute bound on $c$ follows from 
the conjectures about absolute bound of number of rational
points on curves of genus $ > 1$.

Since there are no four consecutive squares in arithmetic progression, the cubic $f(x)$ is square-free.

This leads to the curve $[f(x)=y^2,f(x+1)=z^2]$ which I expect to be genus $4$
in general (and possibly always).

Comment: A smaller example that works for $0 \leq x \leq 5$ is $-4x^3+24x^2-20x+1$.

Comment: @René what is the expected rank of the elliptic curves?

Comment: $4*x^3 - 36*x^2 + 80*x + 1$ works for [0,7]

Comment: I don't know what to expect. My cubic gives an elliptic curve with rank $2$, which is slightly disappointing of course...

Comment: The one up to $7$ is rank $3$. The one up to $6$ doesn't appear to be fast.

Comment: The $[0,7]$ example comes from the rank-$3$ curve of minimal conductor $5077$;
I learned about it from Dick Gross in connection with the paper
$$ $$
Joe P. Buhler, Benedict H. Gross, and Don B. Zagier:
On the Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer for an Elliptic Curve of Rank 3
*Mathematics of Computation* **44** #170 (April 1985), 473-481
$$ $$
$-$ see Table 1 on page 476:
http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2007967/fulltext.pdf

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks. I believe there are infinitely many [0,7] solutions arising from the P_5 identity and elliptic curve of conductor $226432290$.

Comment: Mean infinitely many with squarefree content.

Comment: The mentioned corresponding question about quadratic polynomials is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88233/how-many-consecutive-integers-x-can-make-ax2bxc-square.